# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS not having option to add a new display monitor

Tags: lubuntu

i am using lenovo thinkpad E14 using os - Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. while i am trying to add a new display, i don't see any option in "setting" > "display" options

[this is current laptop hardware and os configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZytz.png)

[In setting > display no option to add a new display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htp93.png)

Comment: Typically you don't have to manually configure a display.  It should be autodetected when you plug it in.  You should see log messages on plug in, and tools like `xrandr` should list it.